# Finding the associated unit eigenvectors from $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}4&0&-2\\0&2&2\\-2&2&3\end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**My work so far**

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=0,\lambda_2=3,\lambda_3=6$

And, the eigenvectors are

$$\lambda_1=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix},\lambda_2=\begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}\ and\ \lambda_3=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\\frac{1}{2}\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus, the associated unit eigenvectors are

$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}^2+(-1)^2+1^2}}\\\frac{-1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}^2+(-1)^2+1^2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}^2+(-1)^2+1^2}}\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{3}\\-\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{2}{3}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2^2+2^2+1^2}}\\\frac{2}{\sqrt{2^2+2^2+1^2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^2+2^2+1^2}}\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{1}{3}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1\\\frac{1}{2}\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{(-1)^2+\frac{1}{2}^2+1^2}}\\\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{(-1)^2+\frac{1}{2}^2+1^2}}\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{(-1)^2+\frac{1}{2}^2+1^2}}\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}-\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{1}{3}\\\frac{2}{3}\end{pmatrix}$$

Is my work correct? Is there a better way at getting these associated unit eigenvectors?

Comment: You have the correct eigenvalues. Did you let the arbitrary variable be 1 to find your eigenvectors?

Comment: @RachidAtmai That's correct. I also just plugged in the eigenvalues into the following formula, to get the associated unit eigenvectors. Would this be the correct process? $$u=\frac{v}{\|v\|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\\\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Yes this is the correct procedure to normalize your vectors, that is to make them unit vectors. Your answers are correct, my above question was confusing more than anything else.

Comment: @RachidAtmai No worries. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Laufen, once you found that the first one comes out to $(1,-2,2)/ 3$ you know automatically that the second and third ones are the same, just with appropriate permutations and $\pm $ signs.